# facebook icon on hover,icon should slide up and like box should appear

Tags: html, css, facebook

I found many posts similar to my requirement,but none of them works..so i m posting here.
   I have a requirement like "facebook icon will be there,which on hover icon will slide up and like box will be displayed in place of facebook  icon"..How to achieve this..

[image]

I tried `position absolute,fixed width,etc`...But no use..

Any help would be appreciable.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you using javascript or jquery to do this? or just css?

Comment: just css..is that not possible with css..

Comment: Either jquery or css,please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with pure CSS using just CSS transforms. [This](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/css3-transitions-and-transforms-from-scratch/) is a pretty good tutorial that should show you how to get your object to slide up using just CSS.

Essentially, you just need `transform: translate(0,50px);` or something like that (along with all the other variations of it required to support it in all browsers. And if you want it to slide over a period of time, you add `transition: all 2s ease-in-out;`. Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asifrc/npH8B/). But more importantly, check out the tutorial mentioned above. It should give you everything you need :)

Comment: $asifrc, atlast i made it..But when it slides up,above the div margin i gave overflow:hidden..But its not hiding..The whole content is visible during slide up and down